# Invoking C++/CLI code from C#

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli

I have a pretty stupid problem: apparently my knowledge of .NET platform and how C# and C++/CLI communicate is very low, maybe it's that I just don't know some lifehacks or need-to-knows of MSVS.

I want to call C++/CLI code from C# (an algorithm is written is native C++ and I want to wrap it). C++/CLI compiles, I add reference to C++/CLI project to my C# console app project. But it  still doesn`t see it. I've been digging this dumb problem for half a day now. Please, help!

And if you know some good theory material to cover such gaps in my understanding, I'd sincerely - much appreciate it. I've read Hogenson and used C++/CLI as glue at work, but I have always had problems with understanding how linker works.

That's solution structure - [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcw2P.jpg)

Test.hxx:

```
#pragma once
#pragma managed

namespace Test
{
    class Test
    {
        public:
            static int Run();
    };

}
```

Test.cxx:

```
#pragma unmanaged
#include <iostream>

#pragma managed
#using <System.dll>
#include "test.hxx"

namespace Test
{
    int Test::Run() { return 42; }
}
```

Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Test;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
      Test.Run();
    }
  }
}
```

Errors:

```
Error   1   The type or namespace name 'Run' does not exist in the namespace 'Test' (are you missing an assembly reference?)    c:\users\denis\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs 13  12  ConsoleApplication1
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Try making Test a public class?

Comment: You compile your c++/cli project as a dll with the /clr option? Then it should be enough to make a reference to the dll in your c# project...

Comment: 1) Public made no difference
2) "Test" project is a DLL compiled with /clr option

I've added reference via <C# app>->References->Add Reference, in the dialog I selected <my C++/CLI DLL>.

Comment: Is there any MSVS module or option I might have forgotten?

Comment: It seems that the Test class itself (Test.Test) is seen, but not it`s method Run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you must define :

public ref class Test

in Test.hxx

Comment: So stupid of me, thanx. It appeared that I forgot about this explicit semantics.

It should've been value class.

Comment: @Denis  we all do any moment :-)